# Resize on touch UIImageView ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview, resize

I'm moving my UIImageView's in my ViewController using these methods:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* bTouch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self Logo_01]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self Logo_02]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self Logo_03]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self Logo_04]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self Logo_05]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self Logo_06]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self Logo_07]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self Logo_08]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self Logo_09]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }
    if ([bTouch.view isEqual:[self Logo_10]]) {
        firstTouchPoint = [bTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        xd = firstTouchPoint.x - [[bTouch view]center].x;
        yd = firstTouchPoint.y - [[bTouch view]center].y;
    }

}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* mTouch = [touches anyObject];
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_01]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];

    }
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_02]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
    }
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_03]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
    }
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_04]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
    }
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_05]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
    }
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_06]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
    }
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_07]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
    }
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_08]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
    }
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_09]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
    }
    if (mTouch.view == [self Logo_10]) {
        CGPoint cp = [mTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        [[mTouch view]setCenter:CGPointMake(cp.x-xd, cp.y-yd)];
    }
    //SETTO LA CORNICE
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(_Image.frame.size.width, _Image.frame.size.height));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [_Image.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //IMMAGINE CON MASCHERA
}
```

i would to resize my UIIMageViews using user's touch control, why it isn't working?

and my second question is:
is possible to set a limit of moving my images?, so, i have a view which contains about 10 images that i'm moving, is it possible to move them only in my view and not in full screen?
Thanks guys.

Comment: Use the Gestures ..!

Comment: You don't need to post all that code. try posting smaller part of the code that still reproduces your problem